# Calling a function in application.js after an AJAX request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ujs

Spinning my wheels trying to figure this out.  I have a link that when clicked retrieves a form from the server.  The form has 3 buttons and 1 text input.  I'm trying to get the non-submit buttons to respond to JS which they don't do after the form is returned from the server.

I've create a function in lists.js which the ajax:success is trying to call, but I'm not doing something right.  I've tested the function in lists.js and I know it works, I'm just not calling it right.

Here are the relevant files.  How do I activate the showPicturePicker function so it can be used after the AJAX response is inserted?

**Lists.js**

```
$("#new_list")
    .bind "ajax:success", (evt, xhr, settings) -> 
        $("#list-item").html(xhr)
        showPicturePicker

showPicturePicker = () ->
    $('#picture').click (e) ->
        e.preventDefault()
        alert "yeah, you figured it out"

$(document).ready showPicturePicker
```

**_new.html.haml (the form returned from the server)**

```
= form_for [@list, @item], :remote => true, :html => {:class => 'form-inline'} do |f|
  .input-append
    = f.text_field "name", :class => 'input-large', :placeholder => "Add item to this list"
    %button#picture.btn
      %span.icon-camera
    %button#link.btn{:style => "font-size: 10px;"} 
      http://
  .secondary-fields{:style => "display: none"}  
    .field.margin
      = f.text_field "link", :placeholder => "http://www.link.com", :style => "width: 325px"
    .field.margin
      = f.file_field "picture"
      = f.hidden_field "picture_cache"
  .clearfix
    = link_to "blah", "#{}", :class => "fuck-me"
  = f.submit "Add Item", :class => 'btn', :id => "add-item"
```

This is a problem i'll need to solve in other places as well and I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

application.js is wrapped with an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression) and variables defined there will not be visible in other files unless you explicitly make them available to the global scope (either by attaching them to window or some other object).

In application.js, try:

```
@showPicturePicker = ->
    ...
# or window.showPicturePicker = ->
```

"Although suppressed within this documentation for clarity, all CoffeeScript output is wrapped in an anonymous function:  (function(){ ... })(); This safety wrapper, combined with the automatic generation of the var keyword, make it exceedingly difficult to pollute the global namespace by accident."

http://coffeescript.org/#lexical_scope

Comment: Thanks for the response Ethan.  The showPicturePicker function was in lists.js and defining it as @showPicturePicker or window.showPicturePicker didn't seem to work.  All i wanted to have happen is make it so that when the form was returned, clicking either the photo button or the link button would slide down a hidden field that the user could input.  I was able to accomplish this through the following:  $("#picture").live "click", (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).closest('#new_item').find('#picture-field').slideToggle("fast")

Comment: This still doesn't address the main issue here though.  The form I return via AJAX has :remote => true and when I submit it, it's not being interpreted as a remote form and using UJS.  How do I deal with that?

Comment: For the most part, I avoid Rails magic when it comes to JS. I'd probably create an event handler for the form submission event and use `$.post` or `$.ajax`.

Comment: yeah, Rails magic can be really frustrating sometimes.  That was going to be my alternate approach, but I'm trying to standardize my approaches around UJS.  If that doesn't work though, I'll mix to do what's necessary!